# Когда пытаюсь снять поток с вебкамеры с помощью pencv в одном адресном пространстве с открытым сокетом получаю ошибку

Tags: c++, сокет, opencv

Когда пытаюсь снять поток с вебкамеры с помощью pencv в одном адресном пространстве с открытым сокетом получаю ошибку

> VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L2: Pixel format of incoming image is unsupported by
>   OpenCV Unable to stop the stream: Device or resource busy

Если видеопоток снимается в отдельном процесее, то все нормально. Как устранить эту проблему? Работаю в Linux

Comment: вы лучше напрямую с V4L2 работайте, вот пример https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/uapi/v4l/capture.c.html,  OpenCV много чего не умеет, многое по умолчанию делает

Comment: @PavelGridin, спасибо. Не могу понять в этом примере, где массив с байтами изображеия и какого он формата

Comment: там надо у камеры список форматов запрашивать, они описаны в каком-то include, в read_frame главный switch ветвится на три разных способа захвата, камера может поддерживать какой-то один, а может и несколько

Comment: есть хорошая программка `v4l2-ctl` ей можно потестировать камеру

Comment: @PavelGridin, код рабочий, проблема в том, что я не могу понять, где в нем сами данные, взятые с вебки, чтоб с ними работать

Comment: данные в `struct buffer  *buffers;`, `buffers[n].start` - данные, `buffers[n].length` - размер

Comment: @PavelGridin, спасибо

Comment: почитайте описание API, там не так уж и много, на день наверное